# Why do goalkeepers wear highly-visible strips?

Tags: football, strategy

I understand the need to have a strip that differentiates goalkeepers from outfield players, but success in top-flight sport often depends on taking advantage of fine margins.

Surely being highly-visible gives an advantage to opposing players as they can see where the 'keeper is and aim shots / take up a position accordingly - even if the 'keeper is not in direct line of sight, there's a player's postional awareness and peripheral vision to consider.

Has there been any research comparing gaudy and muted colours?

Comment: Being highly visible also gives an advantage to the goalkeeper's teammates. If you're defending against a corner kick, for example, you don't want to accidentally barge into your own goalie because you didn't see them.

Comment: @F1Krazy Yep, I thought of including something along those lines in my post but couldn't seem to properly articulate the defence's cost / benefit. Thanks for the example.

Answer (score 1):

The [laws around the player equipment](https://www.thefa.com/football-rules-governance/lawsandrules/laws/football-11-11/law-4---the-players-equipment) say this for clothing colours

> 3. Colours
>
> The two teams must wear colours that distinguish them from each other and the match officials
>
> Each goalkeeper must wear colours that are distinguishable from the other players and the match officials
>
> If the two goalkeepers’ shirts are the same colour and neither has another shirt, the referee allows the match to be played.

My reading of that is that a team cant dictate what their keeper wears. So when a team is designing their goalkeeper kit they'll cross out all the colours that clash with their home and away kit, cross out all the other teams colours, take into [consideration the referee kits](https://refereekithistory.com/premier-league/). You can see why you're left with the gaudier end of the spectrum.